# Salesforce CLI Command to delete Unmanaged Package

Tags: delete, unmanaged-package, cli

We are doing some early spring cleanup and need to uninstall some managed and unmanaged packages.  I can use the CLI command below to delete the Managed packages using the Namespace prefix.

```
sfdx force:source:delete -m "InstalledPackage:sf_chttr_apps, InstalledPackage:GSP_LeadDash, InstalledPackage:ddcAssess, InstalledPackage:rh2" -r
```

However I am unable to determine how to delete the Unmanaged packages.
Worst case I can uninstall them manually.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a CLI command to uninstall packages, but was able to build a script...

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = MetadataServiceExamples.createService();
    List<MetadataService.DeleteResult> results =
        service.deleteMetadata(
            'InstalledPackage', new String[] {
                'ddcAssess', //Data.com Assessment
                'rh2', //Rollup Helper
                'sf_chttr_apps', //Salesforce Mobile Apps
                'GSP_LeadDash' //GSP Lead Conversion Dashboard
            });
  MetadataServiceExamples.handleDeleteResults(results[0]);
```